# how to add a custom design to card component in Materia UI

Tags: css, user-interface, material-ui, frontend

So, im actually a javascript developer and my brother asked me to design a simple page for his business. Im not to good with frontend, so im using Material UI and pasting everything with a little bit of css.

Im doing a form with the card component, that should look like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkqMz.jpg)

my problem is, I dont know how to put the logo (i have it in svg and png) above the card. Should i do it all with css? or how could i do this with MUI? I dont even know where to begin looking

Answer (score 1):

To change insert the logo, just change the relative path in "image".

```
<CardMedia
        component="img"
        height="194"
        image="/static/images/cards/paella.jpg"
        alt="Paella dish"
      />
```

See more in https://mui.com/material-ui/react-card/

With and without MUI, you will experience the same logic behind the style. In the MUI, you'll use box, cardmedia, and form. In html you will use div, img and form.

I suggest you to try using HTML and CSS. When you start with React or another framework, you start building using component libraries. It's not a rule, it's just a suggestion. I made a simple example without MUI to help you:

HTML:

```
<div class="formBox">
  <img
       src="https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/google-logo-1.png"
       width="100px"
       height="auto"
       />
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.formBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-Items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

I suggest you to learn more reading:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

And look for Styled Components and JSS/TSS, maybe you like it.